Trying to make a cart popup using ajax but then after everything my response is shown on the browser dev console but displaying on my page
I'm new to web development and learning how to create restaurant website using laravel. My issue is that I want to make a popup for cart the course I'm using make use of Ajax to get it done everything works fine though except that in my frontend the dynamic contents I've rendered from the database isn't showing but when i inspect the cart the contents are there. Here are my codes
the script...
<script>

/** Load product modal**/
function loadProductModal(productId){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '{{ route("product.modal", ":productId") }}'.replace(":productId", productId),
        success: function(response){
            $(".load_product_modal_body").html(response);
            $("#cartModal").modal('show');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            console.error(error);
        }
    })
}
</script>


the cart popup blade file

 <!-- CART POPUT START -->
 <div class="fp__cart_popup">
    <div class="modal fade" id="cartModal" tabindex="1" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body load_product_modal_body">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- CART POPUT END -->


the cart popup view page

<button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><i
    class="fal fa-times"></i></button>
<div class="fp__cart_popup_img">
<img src="{{ asset($products->thumb_image) }}" alt="{{ $products->name }}" class="img-fluid w-100">
</div>
<div class="fp__cart_popup_text">
<a href="#" class="title">{!! $products->name !!}</a>
<p class="rating">
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
    <span>(201)</span>
</p>
<h4 class="price">$320.00 <del>$350.00</del> </h4>

<div class="details_size">
    <h5>select size</h5>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="large01"
            checked>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="large01">
            large <span>+ $350</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="medium01">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="medium01">
            medium <span>+ $250</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="small01">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="small01">
            small <span>+ $150</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="details_extra_item">
    <h5>select option <span>(optional)</span></h5>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="coca-cola01">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="coca-cola01">
            coca-cola <span>+ $10</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="7up01">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="7up01">
            7up <span>+ $15</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="details_quentity">
    <h5>select quentity</h5>
    <div class="quentity_btn_area d-flex flex-wrapa align-items-center">
        <div class="quentity_btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fal fa-minus"></i></button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="1">
            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></button>
        </div>
        <h3>$320.00</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="details_button_area d-flex flex-wrap">
    <li><a class="common_btn" href="#">add to cart</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


the controller
public function loadProductModal($productId){
        $products = Product::with(['productSizes', 'productVariance'])->findOrFail($productId);

        return view('frontend.layouts.ajax-files.product-popup-modal', compact('products'))->render();
    }

So now instead of rendering in the frontend it's only showing at the browser dev tool console, please someone should help me I've been stuck her for days now
I've tried to get the modal using getElementById but did not work
I've checked online but can't seem to find the issue
I expected my dynamic contents to be shown when I click the cart but it keeps showing the static hard coded contents
